# How to implement In-App purchases in my application

Tags: ios

I want to implement "In-App Purchase" in my iphone application with auto-renewable Subscription, for this i referred the following link:-

http://www.raywenderlich.com/2797/introduction-to-in-app-purchases

but when i want to run on device i get two pop up that asks me for "confirm  subscription" & when i click on Confirm button then i get "login window for login using test user account for sandbox checking" after that it gives me one more pop up to tell "you're currently subscribed to this".

but apple has rejected my application saying that "We found that your app exhibited one or more bugs, when reviewed on iPhone 4 running iOS 5.0.1, on a Wi-Fi network, which is not in compliance with the App Store Review Guidelines. We found when the user makes a purchase, the app displays and error message."

If i run my application on different iphone & ipad 2 with iOS 5.o then it gives me one error message saying "Transaction error: Cannot connect to iTunes Store"

So please guide me for this problem.

Thanks & regards,
Priyanka.

Comment: You have a bug in line 1021. Seriously: How should we know what the problem is without seeing the code?

Comment: Please tell me how to add code here...

Comment: Following is my code Link:-      http://atsdatabase.com/webapps/code.txt

Comment: hello, Please check my code and tell me where i m going wrong in my code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should see this tutorial also - 
http://troybrant.net/blog/2010/01/in-app-purchases-a-full-walkthrough/

Also please post your code so we can help you that!

Answer (score 0):

You can use RMStore A lightweight iOS library for In-App Purchases.
And follow tutorial in the given URL:https://github.com/robotmedia/RMStore 
RMStore adds blocks and notifications to StoreKit, plus receipt verification, content downloads and transaction persistence. All in one class without external dependencies